# How to generate schema diagram using Java schemacrawler API

Tags: schemacrawler

I want to generate schema diagram of a database using Java schemacrawler API .I want the output in HTML format.i am able to generate the schema diagram from command prompt.

Comment: What command are you using to generate the schema diagram?

Comment: I am using schemacrawler through docker image .Also I am able to display weak association . I want to create virtual PK and FK for that created attributes.yaml file but seems it is not working .I am also trying to generate ER diagrams through Java API

Comment: This is my attributes .yml file-name:catalog

weak-associations:

- name: multi_remarks_refere

referenced-table:

catalog: PUBLIC

schema: TEST

name: F_CLAIM

referencing-table:

catalog: public

schema: TEST

name: D_CLAIM

column-references:

CLAIM_KEY: CLAIM_KEY

remarks:

- "FK11"

- "FK12"

Comment: Please follow instructions on https://www.schemacrawler.com/consulting.html to provide more information to diagnose the issue